# Variable substitution in Swift 3+

Tags: swift3, metaprogramming

Is it possible in Swift to do what I think of as meta programming.

For example can I pass a variable in place of an object value.

Say I have a constant struct called `Colors` which has several attributes like this:

```
struct Colors {
    static let grayUltraLight = "#F2F2F2"
    static let grayLight      = "#C4C4C4"
    static let grayDark       = "#585250"
}
```

I can user `Colors.grayLight` to get its hex value but is it possible to pass the key value as a variable? Something like `Colors.myVal` where `myVal` has been set to one of the keys?

Like `myVar = "grayDark"` and then asking for `Colors.myVar` and having it return `"#585250"`

I come from a Ruby development background where this is possible and it's been handy for DRYing up repetitive code.

Comment: I don't understand what you get by doing Colors.myVal (the name of the key?)

Comment: Nope, unlike Ruby, Swift is not dynamic. The closest you can get is subscripts: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html

Comment: @AlmasSapargali - I did not think it was possible but I figured if it were someone on StackOverflow would know. I guess there just has to be a lot of `if` and `case` statements in my code.

Comment: @Dan I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but you could make your `Colors` enum with `String` as raw type. Then create an instance of it, and pass around.